# Is video pre-multiplied or not?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, alpha, rgba

I have an input video that I want to decode and I need to know if the video is pre-multiplied or straight.
Is there any way to figure this out using ffmpeg?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by multiplied?

Comment: rgb already multiplied with the alpha value

Comment: There's no universal metadata flag. Which codec and container?